# Cakephp understanding Localization..?

Tags: cakephp, localization, routes

I guess for most of you this might be a "dumb" question, but I just don't get it.

As I am a beginner, I tried many tutorials I found on google, but none of them is working for me.

I have Cakephp 2.2 running and I'm trying to get the localization working.
I followed the book ( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html )

What I did so far:

```
//In my bootstrap.php I added 
Configure::write('Config.language', 'deu');


// In my AppController.php I added
public function beforeFilter() {
    $locale = Configure::read('Config.language');
    if ($locale && file_exists(VIEWS . $locale . DS . $this->viewPath)) {
        $this->viewPath = $locale . DS . $this->viewPath;
    }
}
```

From my understanding, the visitor should now be redirected to /ger/ .
But nothing is happening...?

Could you please please point me in the right direction..?

Sorry again for the question, but as I'm a beginner I'm stuck now. :(

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Would it not be in the `/deu` folder as that is what you have set `Config.language` to? Also, no it wouldn't redirect the user - it would look for the view files in `/app/View/deu/Pages/` instead of `/app/View/Pages/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this code will do is edit the `$this->viewPath` variable.

This will make CakePHP look in a different directory from the standard when calling `render()`. This is normally done if you intend to create different folders, each of which contains the View files for a specific localisation.

If your View folder currently looks like this:

```
View
    - Elements
    - Emails
    - Errors
    - Helper
    - ...
```

It should, instead, look like this:

```
View
    - deu
        - Elements
        - Emails
        - Errors
        - Helper
        - ...
    - Elements
    - Emails
    - Errors
    - Helper
    - ...
```

In this way, you can specify entirely different View files for lots of different localisations. The folders in the root directory should be the default localisation.

The reason it currently isn't doing anything is because it can't find the relevant view files when it makes the `file_exists()` check. Once you have restructured as necessary it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! I added the "deu-tree".

When I run "debug(Configure::read('Config.language'));" it returns 'deu'

But "debug($this->viewPath);" returns 'Pages'

I thought it should return 'deu/Pages'. Any idea why?

Comment: No problem =) I know it's a basic question, but are you definitly calling `debug($this->viewPath);` after your AppController's beforeFilter() is called?

Comment: I've added the debug line to default.ctp in all views before "echo $content_for_layout".

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right. Ok, how about trying some `die()` statements in and around the `beforeFilter()` function? Try putting `die($this->viewPath)` inside the if statement, after the value is supposed to be changed. Let me know what happens =)

Comment: After searching the internet the whole weekend, I realized that on my server the file exists check is only working like this:
`file_exists(APP.'View'.DS.$this->viewPath.DS.$locale)`

Thanks again for your help